# Rails 4: Carrierwave/AWS - Excon::Errors::SocketError / getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Want to use the carrierwave gem and AWS to upload images from my app.
But when i upload the image and submit get errors

```
Excon::Errors::SocketError in MoviesController#create
getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided
```

trace

```
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:29:in `create'

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"laitXtzkMnWd/EHtVjFx0X5vE0P4kowXu84wH8fEVOQ=",
 "movie"=>{"title"=>"new ",
 "description"=>"te",
 "movie_length"=>"12",
 "director"=>"12",
 "rating"=>"12",
 "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc913845fb0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/s8/fd5_m1_d3436ptj9znpcy3cc0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150211-642-1ow2dmn>,
 @original_filename="IMG_0892.JPG",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"movie[image]\"; filename=\"IMG_0892.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">},
 "commit"=>"Create Movie"}
```

MoviesController#create

```
def create
@movie = Movie.new(movie_params)

respond_to do |format|
  **if @movie.save**<--- Error
    format.html { redirect_to @movie, notice: 'Movie was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @movie }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @movie.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```

but i thinks it something to do with my aws setup  because i was able to create images without the AWS, but now since using the fog gem & AWS access & id keys it doesn't work

config/initialiser.rb

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'AKIAIxxxxxxA',                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'UdRxhdOHoaxxxxxxxx3I9+vIId+',
    :region => 'Ireland',                      # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'moviesdemo'                     # required
end
```

After searching for a solution, i believe you have to add the region now , but this does not work.

```
gemfile 

source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby "2.0.0"
gem 'rails', '4.1.7'
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
gem 'pg', group: :production
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog'
```

image.uploader rb

## encoding: utf-8

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
  storage :fog
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your region should be something like "eu-west-1" not "Ireland":

```
:region => 'eu-west-1',
```

Though you should check your region on your bucket to make sure you are picking the right one.

Comment: For people in the US with the same error, thinking that their region is 'us-standard', it's really 'us-east-1'.